# Application crashes when i try to restore the theme last set by user?

Tags: android

This is my code where user sets the theme:

```
case R.id.darkorangetheme:
          ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_DARKORANGE);
          editor.putInt("mytheme", appliedtheme);
          editor.commit();
          return true;
      case R.id.bluetheme:
          ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE);
          editor.putInt("mytheme", appliedtheme);
          editor.commit();
          return true;
      case R.id.greentheme:
          ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_GREEN);
          editor.putInt("mytheme", appliedtheme);
          editor.commit();
          return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

This is the code of my theme changer class:

```
package com.example.calculator;
```

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class ThemeChanger 
{
    private static int sTheme;

```
public final static int THEME_DARKORANGE = 0;
public final static int THEME_GREEN = 1;
public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 3;


public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(ActionBarActivity activity, int theme)
{
    switch (sTheme)
    {
    default:
    case THEME_DARKORANGE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Darkorange);
        break;
    case THEME_GREEN:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
        break;
    case THEME_BLUE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
        break;
    case THEME_LIGHT:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
    }
}
```

}

Now my onCreate Method:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{

private TextView inputText,resultText,memoryStatText;
public static int button1,buttoncos,buttonmadd;
double firstNumber=0,secondNumber=0,result=0;
int firstOperand=0,TotalOperator=0;
Stack<String> mInputStack;
Stack<String> mOperationStack;
boolean resetInput = false;
boolean hasFinalResult = false;
int appliedtheme;

String mDecimalSeparator;
double memoryValue = Double.NaN;

SharedPreferences preferences = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);      
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
    appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this,appliedtheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    button1 = preferences.getInt("DigitButtonStyle",defaultValue);
    buttonmadd = preferences.getInt("MemoryButtonStyle",defaultValue);
    buttoncos = preferences.getInt("FunctionButtonStyle",defaultValue);
```

Now my question is why does my application crash?

Here is my logcat

```
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:161)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:38)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
03-19 08:02:05.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3217):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Related: you're always saving `0` to the `mytheme` preference instead of the User's chosen theme.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, thanx. But still, why does my application crash when set to zero it should make my theme orange and not crash.

Comment: Ah, I see the definition now in your other file. Anyways, provide more code. Where is `preferences` instantiated? The earliest it can be done is in `onCreate()`. I also don't see where you're calling `onActivityCreateSetTheme` from. I'd also think that you should be getting an infinite restart loop once it doesn't crash.

Comment: Yes you are right, i edited my code its working but goes in an infinite loop. Why is that happening.

Comment: Refer to my answer below. It tries to explain your issues and comes up with a fix. It should work but given the lack of information you have provided, I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: @A--C is on the right track.... if you would just show the code that is actually failing, though, it would be much easier to help.  The error is in MainActivity's constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd change your code based on the information in your question.

I'd make `onActivityCreateSetTheme` accept in the theme number as well:

```
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
{
    switch (theme)
    {
    default:
    case THEME_DARKORANGE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Darkorange);
        break;
    case THEME_GREEN:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
        break;
    case THEME_BLUE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
        break;
    case THEME_LIGHT:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
    }
}
```

I'd change `preferences` and any other variables that require a `Context` so they get a reference in `onCreate()` rather than outside the class. When an `Activity` is simply instantiated, it is far from being a full `Activity`. Thus, `onCreate()` ensures that we are dealing with a full `Activity` instance avoiding "mysterious" NPEs.

I'd also change `onCreate()` as so:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  preferences = //get preferences however you need to.
  int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
  appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
  ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, appliedtheme);

  setContentView (R.layout.main);
}
```

`changeToTheme()` *always* restarts the Activity. Given the lack of code, if you have no checks in place, you risk getting into an infinite Activity start loop. Thus, `onActivityCreateSetTheme()` is the better choice. Themes should also be set before `setContentView()`, so that has been changed accordingly up above.

Comment: Thanx, its not crashing now but theme does not take any other value than orange. Can you help me if i post my complete code, because i can't find any problem.

Comment: @user3404195 it depends where you're *saving* the theme. Is it really not something that you can figure out yourself? I *did* answer your question about why its crashing, why not accept this answer and make another question for fresh eyes to look at? Also, if you **didn't** change my code at all and it is always orange, then you saved something correctly at some point since the default should be *blue*.

Comment: @user3404195 actually you may not need to make a new question `appliedtheme` never has its value changed. I'll edit my answer because it should be a simple fix.

Comment: So i should post it as a new question, then?

Comment: I thought editor.putInt("mytheme", appliedtheme);  was setting value of applied theme.

Comment: @user3404195 `appliedTheme` has a value, but you never change its value inside the `switch`.

Comment: It still shows just orange theme, even if i set theme directly like this: ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this,ThemeChanger.THEME_GREEN);

Comment: @user3404195 Have you restarted the Activity after changing the theme? Otherwise I'm stumped too so you should make a new question.

Comment: If i write ThemeChanger.changeToTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_GREEN); to change theme then app goes in infinite loop, but still even when it is not responding its theme is orange.

Comment: Then I can't help you any further, sorry. At least we solved one of your issues. Make a new question, other users will be glad to help. Make sure to include **all relevant code* in your new question. That way people don't guess.